# How do I create spacing between these list elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm just wondering how I would put a 3 pixel space between the different list items in the following html? Also, how do I properly vertically align the text within those lists?

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 318px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    background-color: #f99400;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #fbc486;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

So yeah, I just want to put a 3 pixel break of empty space (same as background colour) in between those 3 items to separate them in the navbar. And for some reason the vertical alignment of the text isn't working right.

Comment: if you want to separate them horizontally, you can use padding. If you want to separate them vertically, you can use line-height.

Comment: Could be missing something here but do you not just need li
{
float:left;
    margin-right:3px;
}

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
li + li {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3vvZn/).

References:

- [CSS adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: Thank you so much, such a quick response too. Really appreciated!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, and I'm glad to have been of help. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want your text properly alligned within the a tag, use the same line-height as the font size is. e.g.:

```
a {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `margin-bottom`:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/3vvZn/1/)

```
li{
   margin-bottom:3px;
}
```